# android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" showing error for a project with the minimum SDK as 2.2

Tags: android, sdk, landscape, screen-orientation

I'm trying to set `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` for one of my activities, to enable landscape left and landscape right.

In my project properties, I've set the project build target to Android 2.2. In my manifest, the minimum SDK version is set to Android 2.2 as well (API level 8):
The line in my manifest is:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
```

According to the docs, the "sensorLandscape" attribute should be available to me, but still, when I try setting it, the error I get is "`error: Error: String type not allowed (at "screenOrientation" with value "sensorLandscape")`".

Am I missing some extra setting somewhere?

Comment: I know it could be silly but try to close eclipse and reopen it again, then do clean project. Sometimes such cases happen to me with eclipse!

Comment: Well it's not silly because I've seen it happen quite a lot; Sadly though, didn't help :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["sensorLandscape"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen):Landscape orientation, but can be either normal or reverse landscape based on the device sensor.**Added in API level 9.** so i think your minsdkVersion should be **9 instead of 8**...

Comment: I believe you're correct. When I used the API Level filter on the docs, it didn't gray out the sensorLandscape part and that threw me off.

Comment: no..targetSDK >= 9 is enough to get it work, you could safely set the minSDK to 8 and I've it working right now, but I can't figure what is your problem though

Comment: Hi Mahdi, sorry but I deleted my last comment. There's some funny business going on and I'd best avoid making a concrete statement until I can get to the bottom of this lol. I do feel like there's a bug. The compiler errors appear depending on the deployment target I set in the project properties, regardless of whether the minSDK in my manifest is set to 8 or 9.

Comment: so..if you set the deployment target to something lower than 9 it will   show the error..If I understood you correctly, that might not be a bug since this property is added to API 9 and the target should be >=9.

Comment: If,the sensorLandscape is an optional one.. i.e your application can also run without this specific screenOrientation attribute then targetsdk>=9 is enough.. but if you compulsary need that attribute for your application minsdk should be 9

Comment: Hi all; My understanding of Deployment Target vs minSDKVersion was wrong. Thanks for all your help! Deployment target tells the compiler exactly what API level to build against; minSDKversion tells Google Play what devices can install your app. Having the minSDKVersion < Deployment target means your app handles missing functionality gracefully. Sorry for the runaround!

Answer (score 2):

Aha! This environment is just /made/ to drive you nuts, isn't it?

For my project I was setting the minSDK to 9 or even 12, nothing made any difference.

Of course, when I'd created the project, I'd built it for minSDK 8...which means I had the android-8 (2.2) library listed for my project to link against.

For any other frustrated newbies (like me) that run into this the steps I took to resolve it are:
In the Package Explorer on the left, right click on 'Android 2.2'.
Select 'Build Path->Remove from Build Path'.
Right click on the project name, select 'Build Path->Configure Build Path'
Click on 'Android' in the menu on the left.
untick the 'Android 2.2' box, and tick the 'Android 2.3.1' box (or as appropriate).
Click 'Apply' then 'OK'.
Right click on the project again and select 'Build Path->Add Libraries'
Select "Android Classpath Container", click 'Next'.
Click 'Finish'.

Now, clear your logs, clean the project, and try a build again.  Hopefully, that will work better for you as it did for me.