# Screen gets rotated even after locking device's rotation in Android

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

I am using this in my manifest to rotate my app based on screen orientation

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenLayout|screenSize"
```

The problem is even after I lock my devices screen orientation, app still rotate if I change the orientation of the device.

I tried

```
android:screenOrientation="user"
```

But that makes my app rotate to portrait also which I don't want.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I have already answerd this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208729/error-string-types-not-allowed-at-androidconfigchanges-in-manifest-file/11208857#11208857

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this question you should find your answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675750/lock-screen-orientation-android).
You have to set

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Best wishes

Comment: But that restricts the rotation to landscape right. I need both landscape right and landscape left.

Comment: Ah ok sry. Havent seen this restriction. May that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179508/androidscreenorientation-sensorlandscape-showing-error-for-a-project-with-the) could help you